# AG GRID - how to delete/hide a rom using custom context menu

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I've been trying to remove a row through an actions function within a custom context menu for a while, but nothing I do seems to work...

```
         gridOptions = {
          defaultColDef: {
            flex: 1,
            minWidth: 150,
            resizable: true,
            filter: true,
            floatingFilter: true,
            sortable: true,
          },
          rowData: ObjData,
          pagination: true,
          paginationPageSize: 10,
          getContextMenuItems(event) {
              return [
                {
                  name: 'Delete Row',
                  action: () => {
                    // const selectedRows = event.api.getSelectedRows();
                    // event.api.applyTransaction({ remove: selectedRows });

                    // const colDef = event.column.getColDef();
                    // colDef.cellStyle = {'backgroundColor': '#f00'}

                    // var column = gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows();
                    // column.cellStyle = { 'opacity': '0' };
                  },
                }
              ]
          },
```

I just need to hide/delete the row...

Comment: Your code is working. Please check [Plunkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/203DsGnN2PYeIU1n?open=main.js&preview) once. Btw context menu is `enterprise` feature.

Comment: I'm using enterprise version, and this exemple you posted only works if the row is selected first.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

```js
getContextMenuItems(event) {
  var result = [
    {
                  name: 'Delete Row',
                  action: () => {
                    
                     const selectedRows =[event.node.data];
                     event.api.applyTransaction({ remove: selectedRows });

                     const colDef = event.column.getColDef();
                     colDef.cellStyle = {'backgroundColor': '#f00'}

                     var column = gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows();
                     column.cellStyle = { 'opacity': '0' };
                  },
     },
       ]
```

[Plunkr Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/rBIswrlJ66AELpq5?open=main.js&preview)

Comment: It does! thank you so much, your a life savior.